# Redirecting back button to specific page using history API

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I have an online test which runs over 5 web pages sequentially without pause.  I want the back button, if used, to redirect to the page before the test pages, preventing it being used to cycle thru the test pages. I thought the history API might be the way to go and tried using it with this script:

```
var stateObj = { url: "/index.php/toeic_introduction"};

// Updates the current history entry   timerArray[i][2].
window.history.replaceState(stateObj, "","/index.php/toeic_introduction");

// Creates a new history entry.
window.history.pushState(stateObj, "","/index.php/toeic_introduction");
```

This works to the extent that the url is displayed in the address line but the back button does not redirect as required. I'm not even sure whether control over the back button can be achieved in this way. I had thought of disabling the back button and have looked around online but this option seems to be rather problematic. I certainly would be welcome any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a pushtState with Javascript history, you should use window.onpopstate to manage the back button action.

You will find all the needed documentation in this page :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to bind to [popState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) event and put your redirection logic there like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
          // your logic here
        });
      }
   });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The address line does not show "/index.php/toeic_introduction" after the test is started. I've checked with an alert and the function is being accessed.